# JPA error with oneToMany relation in play framework

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

I'm using play-1.2.3.

I have two classes some kind of these:

LabelItem:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T_LABEL_ITEM")
public class LabelItem extends Model{
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="labelItem")
  public List<LabelValue> labelValues;
}
```

LabelValue:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T_LABEL_VALUE")
public class LabelValue extends Model{
  @ManyToOne
  public static LabelItem labelItem;
  public static String value;
}
```

When i start my play server, the error page shows up:

```
"A JPA error occurred (Unable to build EntityManagerFactory): mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: models.LabelValue.labelItem in models.LabelItem.labelValues"
```

Something more : the T_Label_VALUE table in database has only a id column,the "value" column didn't been created.

Can anyone help ? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static variables are not persisted by JPA. Make labelItem an instance variable if you want it managed by JPA.